# My canvas onclick is giving me results from the wrong canvas - how do I make sure the right canvas responds?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

So I have a canvas.

```
<canvas style ="width: 30em; height:30em; overflow:visible;"  id="GraphCanvas<?echo $this->id;?>"></canvas>
```

I'm generating these in PHP. I then make a chart -

```
    var ourChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: <?echo "'".$this->graphtype."'"?>,
      data: {
        labels: <?echo $arrParsed["labels"];?>, 
        keys: <?echo $arrParsed["keys"];?>,
        datasets: [{
          data:<?echo $arrParsed["data"];?>,
          backgroundColor: <?echo $arrParsed["color"]?>
        }]
      },
      options: {
        //Irrelevant graphics options
      }
    });
```

And then I make an onclick, and attach it to the canvas, so I can do fancy things -

```
var canvas =  document.getElementById("GraphCanvas<?echo $this->id;?>");
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
      var slice = ourChart.getElementAtEvent(e);
        if(!slice.length) {
          return;
        }
        key = slice[0]._chart.config.data.keys[slice[0]._chart.config.data.labels.indexOf(slice[0]._model.label)]; //The array is indexed differently than the keys, and might be fubar, so we have to actually check the key at the same array index of the label we're looking at.  The key is the array index of the arrBuckets[] item in this graph!  EDIT: chartjs provides a _model that has the index, so you can just use that instead of fishing like I did.  Leaving this how it is because it works and for educational purposes


        console.log(slice);
        console.log(key);
        document.getElementById('bucketdrillid').value=key;
        //document.getElementById('graph<?echo $this->id;?>').submit();
}
```

I add a second canvas, with ID 2, then a third canvas, with ID 3.

Now I have 3 lovely charts, with 3 lovely chart graphs.  To trigger this function, I click in a canvas.

But no matter which canvas I click, the object in slice that is returned is always from the last canvas loaded, not the one I actually clicked on.

Even stranger, the location I click on one canvas actually maps perfectly to where the slices actually are on the later canvas - so if I click in the top left of the topmost, the getElementAtEvent returns the top-left slice of the bottom-most chart!

How do I make sure that, when I have multiple canvasses, clicking on a particular canvas gives me back the element from that canvas, and not the last canvas loaded?

Comment: In the onclick function, e.target will access the element that was clicked. You are using `var slice = ourChart.getElementAtEvent(e);` So take a look at your `getElementAtEvent` function, because it is what is returning the last canvas.

Comment: Blah, sadly it's not mine, but something built into chartjs.  I'll go bug the owner - thank you!